# Boost fails silently when trying to check for when a file can't be modified

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to test when boost can and can't modify files/folders so I can catch exceptions for when it fails but when I make boost purposely fail at modifying a folder, it fails silently without throwing any warnings or errors.

I've all ready tried checking the permissions of the folder with `boost::filesystem::file_status`, but that returns a permission value that is OS specific(I'm testing on linux so I get a number for permission value).

Code

```
boost::filesystem::path TestFolder("./TestFolder");
boost::filesystem::create_directory(TestFolder)
```

Edit: what happens wen i try to run the code: I execute the code above on a folder  that my program doesn't have write permissions to and boost silently fails to modify it

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've shown?  What do you wish or expect would happen?

Comment: You have to provide more information. On which platform do you compile ? What is exact error message ?

Comment: There are no error messages, thats the problem. I'm trying to make boost fail on purpose so I can catch errors for when boost can and can't modify files but boost is throwing none